# Can I authenticate multiple times to one access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, security, denial-of-service

I'm attempting to test the security and stability of a new wireless access controller and assigned, it a has a /24 subnet of IP addresses to use for giving clients DHCP. 
I'm wondering if its possible to

- A) exhaust this limit of IP's thereby performing a denial of service and
- B) if its possible to do this from one machine (authenticating and 'taking' multiple IP addresses)

Has this been tried before or are there any tools or resources available to do this?

Comment: By changing his mac address, using macchanger commande, a client can get multiples ip address.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to exhaust all the available addresses of your DHCP server.

[WP: DHCP (Security)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Security)

> [Presenting false credentials] allows DHCP clients to exhaust the DHCP server's store of IP addresses—by presenting new credentials each time it asks for an address, the client can consume all the available IP addresses on a particular network link, preventing other DHCP clients from getting service.

One way to mitigate this problem is to encrypt your Wifi. Only clients that have access can request an IP.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of tools to load-test a DHCP server. Just search for "DHCP load tester" or "DHCP server test tool" or anything similar.

You can do it without changing your MAC address, by just changing your DHCP Client ID in each request. So you could maintain one single Wi-Fi connection and still take up hundreds of DHCP leases. This is probably how must of those DHCP server load testers work.

Maintaining multiple simultaneous Wi-Fi connections from one Wi-Fi client card to one AP is technically possible, but may be hard to do with most consumer cards. The 802.11 protocol requires that you use a different MAC address for each connection, and most cards won't handle that in hardware, so you'd have to do it in software. Or you can buy 802.11 AP load testing hardware such as an IxVeriWave module for an Ixia chassis, but that's a pretty pricey product unless you're going to be spending lots of time load testing lots of Wi-Fi APs and controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [MDK3](http://aspj.aircrack-ng.org/#mdk3). In addition, [Kali Linux](http://www.kali.org) is a good virtual machine to run it on that includes much more.